# How can i tell when a simple png animation in iOS is finished?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview

This is the classic animation, but I need to know when it actually finishes. thanks

```
UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
campFireView.frame = CGRectMake(255.0f,0.0f,512.0f,384.0f);

campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_launch_up_low_00000.png"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_launch_up_low_00001.png"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_launch_up_low_00002.png"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_launch_up_low_00003.png"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_launch_up_low_00004.png"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_launch_up_low_00005.png"],
  ,nil];


  campFireView.animationDuration = 0;
  campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

  [campFireView startAnimating];

  [self.view addSubview:campFireView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pain to detect UIImageView animation.. but if you don't mind mess you can do something like this..

```
UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
campFireView.frame = CGRectMake(255.0f,0.0f,512.0f,384.0f);

campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_launch_up_low_00000.png"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_launch_up_low_00001.png"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_launch_up_low_00002.png"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_launch_up_low_00003.png"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_launch_up_low_00004.png"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"wish_launch_up_low_00005.png"],
  ,nil];


  campFireView.animationDuration = 4;  // <--- I changed the duration.. 
  campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

  [campFireView startAnimating];

  [self.view addSubview:campFireView];
```

...

```
  // detect it with timer
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)OnTimer {
    if ( [campFireView isAnimating] )
    {
        // still animating
    }
    else
    {
        // Animating done
    }

}
```

this is just an example but if your animation duration is less then timer you can check it with timer to validate isAnimating...

However, there are many option to animate other the UIImageView...

Comment: Thanks. Jumping into OpneGL for my next animations. This is a clever hack for sure.